# Set the last element equal to the first element in a multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

For example I have an array:

```
[[[[1 2][3 4]]][[[1 2][3 4]]]]
```

How would I set 4 equal to 1? I used

```
array[-1][-1][-1][-1] = array[0][0][0][0]
```

but I got an error because of it later on. Is there a more general way of doing this?

Comment: Please format your input array to be valid Python.

Comment: What is the error that you get?  That statement should work (although it would be more concise and more efficient to write it `array[-1,-1,-1,-1] = array[0,0,0,0]`).

Answer (score 0):

You can "cheat" by updating the flattened array:

```
a = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]]])

a.flat[-1] = a.flat[0]

a
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 1]]])
```

Comment: You can use the `flat` iterator if you want to modify `a` itself, rather than make a copy: `a.flat[-1] = a.flat[0]`  (

Comment: Oh, nice, I didn't know about `flat`.  Thanks, will update!